# sql order by logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains two columns. One of the columns contain text and the other contain integer values.

I need this table to be ordered by the integer value (higher values to the top) but if the integer value equals to 0 then I need that row to be ordered alphabetically aswell. Lets say that I have this table

```
TextCol|IntCol|
-------|------|
Delta  |  0   |
Alpha  |  0   |
Beta   |  3   |
Sierra |  2   |
Gama   |  1   |
```

Now I need this :

```
TextCol|IntCol|
-------|------|
Beta   |  3   |
Sierra |  2   |
Gama   |  1   |
Alpha  |  0   |
Delta  |  0   |
```

What would be the SQL query for this?

Comment: Please show the queries you actually tried to solve your problem.

Comment: SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY age DESC, name ASC ; where test->tablename,age->numeric; name->text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following solution using the [`CASE WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY intColumn DESC, 
         CASE WHEN intColumn = 0 THEN stringColumn END ASC
```

**Here you can find a example:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a982a/1

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the CASE statement? Kool-Mind's comment on the question looks like it would work.  First order by number, then name.  This way it would also be organized by the name with the number rather than only at 0.

Comment: I tried this and it works just fine . My ordering priority is numbers. High to low . But if the number is 0 , it should start ordering alphabeticly. Sebastians query does this fine.

Comment: @Cody360c The question is about ordering the second column alphabeticly only if the number column is 0 - not every time.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch I suppose so.  In that case, personally, I would have had one answer for exactly what they wrote and then had another answer with the double ORDER BY with an explanation.  But it doesn't matter because a correct answer is a correct answer and you answered it correctly : )

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

- **ISNULL(IntCol,0) Desc** : give you integer value by higher value to lower value. If any value null then it will convert to "0"
- **TextCol** : it will order text column to ascending value.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY ISNULL(IntCol,0) DESC, TextCol
  ```